# Can't open connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I develop an applivation with very load(request).
I used following technologies in my appliation:

1. Jpa/Hibernate as persistense layer
2. Spring and Spring Dao
3. C3p0 as connection pooling

my problem is : I run my application , when number of request increase, throw exception in 
persistense layer that"Cannt open connection"
I increase oracle max session but my problem not solve
I indept in C3p0 document and test its options but my problem not solve.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question. Do you mind editing it, and adding all important information (connection pool settings, Oracle profile restrictions etc.) so that there is sufficient clarity?

Comment: My c3p0 setting is :                                   initialPoolSize = 5
minPoolSize  = 5
maxPoolSize = 100                                             maxIdleTime =30000
unreturnedConnectionTimeout = 90
propertyCycle = 60
acquireRetryDelay = 1000
maxConnectionAge = 0
acquireIncrement = 1
acquireRetryAttempts =0

of course I test C3p0 by several value and by other options but don't change.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?  It could be that you have too many open connections because you are somehow leaking connections (unlikely with Hibernate) or it could be that you suddenly cannot access the database for some other reason (maybe something is shutting it down)

Comment: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@10241ae -- timeout at awaitAvailable()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You increased max sessions on Oracle, but you didn't increase the max size of your connection pool. The exception is telling you that your pool is exhausted. Either find what's holding connections open and get them released sooner, or increase the number of max active connections in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to post the Spring configuration for your DataSource.  I would expect something like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.connection.url}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${jdbc.connection.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.connection.password}"/>
  <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/> 
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"/>
</bean>
```

With another bean configured where the dataSource is passed by reference:

```
<bean id="mySampleDao" class="com.example.dao.MySampleDao">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Is this what you have?

What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Yes,I have above configuration. I'm using `Oracle 11g`.